# Where might I find the definition of a method (used from javascript) of a flash object?

Tags: javascript, flash, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to reverse engineer - for fun - a browser-based flash game.

In the javascript code I see a call like:

```
var game = document.getElementById('flashgame');
var result = game.getSomeResult();
```

The object is embedded like this:

```
<object id="game"...>
 <param ...>
 ...
</object>
```

I have decompiled the source, and there's no trace of any 'getSomeResult' method.

I have analyzed the javascript object that I receive, and it contains some properties whose names I can't even find in the source code. Some properties of that object though are in the source.

So where could the definition of `getSomeResult` be hiding? Could it reside in some other files, saved locally on my computer?

Any ideas?

Comment: Only you can answer this question. Do you have other files locally? If yes check them, if not then check the decompiled source & see if it loads any other extra SWF files that may contain `getSomeResult` function. Also is the code obfuscated? like some names are obsure like `function _lw755 (_ab12:int) : void { ..code etc... }`? If yes then one of those could be `getSomeResult` just obfuscated to look like `_lw755`. **Note** some things cannot always be obfuscated or else Flash won't work, so those become the ones you can find easily in the source...

Comment: I looked for the function in all the .sol files that the game seems to use, but still nothing. I'll just keep looking (though I haven't seen any method names be obfuscated, only that the decompiler couldn't fetch the parameter names, and they're all like `_arg1`. I'll keep looking, thanks!